# How to create a file in `HDFS` dynamically

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I want to create some files in `HDFS` dynamically based on the time stamp.

I can do this in Linux and create the files.

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log

touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
```

Is there a way to do this in `HDFS`. I would like to use this feature in shell scripts.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hdfs dfs -touchz /home/$USER/logs/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.success_log
```

Or in your way,

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
hdfs dfs -touchz /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
```

Comment: Please do not edit questions for successive problems. Please open a new question on it.

Comment: Yes, use `hdfs dfs -appendTofile`. Refer syntax [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile)